# Как прочитать русский текст в файле(Питон)

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, visual-studio-code, текст

Есть файл settings.txt, там написано Матеша

Выводит вот это: РњР°С‚РµС€Р°.

если что использую текстовый редактор VS code

Comment: Указать кодировку при открытии файла.

Comment: Надо выбрать правильную кодировку: `UTF-8`, `Windows 1251` или `cp866`. Справа внизу в окне редактора, например, отображается текущая кодировка и её там можно поменять.